# How do I specify multiple experiments in a flex template run?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am using Dataflow flex templates and am trying to launch as a job with GPU. I am following docs here to build my template from base nvidia image: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-gpus

I want to run the template with a GPU attached. This requires experiments:

- `"worker_accelerator=type:nvidia-tesla-t4l;count:1;install-nvidia-driver`
- `"use_runner_v2"`

I believe these need to be specified separately rather than as a list. Or at least I haven't found a way to do that and the docs specify two --experiment arguments. From looking at docs I also believe that I need to specify the experiments as part of the `--parameters` argument as there is no `--experiments` argument for running flex templates.

I have tried the following:

In gcloud command line:

- Specified `experiments` argument twice under `--parameters`. In this case it only assigns the second specified experiment.

  `gcloud dataflow flex-template run "test-flex" --template-file-gcs-location=<LOCATION> --parameters=source="bigquery",experiments="worker_accelerator=type:nvidia-tesla-t4;count:1;install-nvidia-driver",experiments="use_runner_v2" --max-workers=1 --region=us-east4 --worker-zone=us-east4-b`
- Assigned `experiments` in `--parameters` to specify the GPU and set `--additional-experiments` to `use_runner_v2`.

  `gcloud dataflow flex-template run "test-flex" --template-file-gcs-location=<LOCATION> --parameters=source="bigquery",experiments="worker_accelerator=type:nvidia-tesla-t4;count:1;install-nvidia-driver" --max-workers=1 --region=us-east4 --worker-zone=us-east4-b --additional-experiments='use_runner_v2'`

This caused an error:

> ```
>    ERROR: (gcloud.dataflow.flex-template.run) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The template parameters are invalid. Details:
> experiments: Runtime parameter experiments should not be specified in both parameters field and environment field.
> ```

I can get each experiment to work separately but cannot get them to both work. Is there a simple fix for this? I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation nor figured it out myself.

Please let me know any additional information you need me to provide.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass both experiments in additional-experiments:

```
--additional-experiments=worker_accelerator=type:nvidia-tesla-t4;count:1;install-nvidia-driver,use_runner_v2
```

```
--additional-experiments=worker_accelerator=type:nvidia-tesla-t4;count:1;install-nvidia-driver \
--additional-experiments=use_runner_v2
```

should both work.